# What is the best Material Design UI framework

Tags: user-interface, polymer, material-design, angular-material, materialize

I started to build a web application for HR Management and thought of applying Material Design concepts for interface. When I searched I found there are many frameworks for it such as

1. Angular Material
2. Materialize
3. Polymer

I want to select one of these material design frameworks for my project. There are couple of concerns I have about these frameworks.

1. What is the stability and the future maintainability of framework
2. How easy to customize the framework according to our new requirements and components
3. Do others use the framework
4. Which has most of the features

By considering above concerns can some one advice me what to use as the Material Design framework?

Comment: Depends what you're truly trying to accomplish! Do you even need a full framework or could you get by with simply using Material Lite? http://www.getmdl.io/started/

Comment: Seems like material lite have only limited features compared to other frameworks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will share my finding based on different criteria

1. Browser Compatibility

   I) Materialize supports in all 3 browsers.

   II) Polymer does not support in IE and safari

   III) Angular Material its not mentioned clearly on the documentation.
2. Stability

   I) Materialize Still under development but because it's just js and css
        you will be able to keep up with it.

   II) Polymer Still under development. Next versions can be entirely
         different.

   III) Angular Material Still under development. Next versions can be
          entirely different.
3. Material look and feel

   I) Materialize not pure material design.

   II) Polymer pure material design.

   III) Angular Material pure material design.
4. Features

   I) Materialize feature less compared to other two.

   II) Polymer feature rich.

   III) Angular Material feature rich.
5. Future

   I) Materialize not clear.

   II) Polymer very clear because of google doing it.

   III) Angular Material very clear because of google doing it.

Overall It's hard to say which is best. If not for the lack of support in IE (HR domain lots of people still use IE) my choice will be Polymer.If someone knows about Angular Material's browser compatibility please comment.

Comment: Thanks for the information and it really helped me.

Comment: @thilanka happy to help.

Comment: Polymer is supported by IE 10 and Safari via Polyfills - https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/resources/compatibility.html. However the Android browser isn't supported (Chrome for Android is fine).
And also v1.0 has been released already.

Answer (score 4):

I will answer based on the concerns you have. 
I don't know much about materialize, but by looking at their websites, I think I can relate it with other libraries.

1. I feel Polymer is much more stable than the other the other two as it is production ready with version 1.0. While the other two are still under development and their 1st version isn't even out yet. 
   Polymer and angular-material both are projects by google, so future maintainability will be proper. I am not so hopeful about materialize.
2. I have worked more on angular-material and it is much more customizable than the other two.
3. I don't have the statistics.
4. Angular-Material and polymer have much more features than materialize. Angular-material is based purely on material-design and has more material-design components than the other two. While polymer is composed of different API's (example:google API's) which can be implemented in your application very easily.

I would like to conclude by saying that if you want to use pure material-design then you should go for angular-material.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes I agree that Polymer and Angular material is feature rich. But browser compatibility is also a matter for me and it's not clear about browser compatibility of those two.